# What is the type of a function component in React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm using React with TypeScript, and have two function components:

1. `List` which represents a list of things
2. `Lists` which renders all the lists given to it inside a `<ul>`

This is how I want to define `Lists`:

```js
export function List() { ... }

export interface IListsProps {
    lists: List[];
}

export default function Lists({ lists }: IListsProps) { ... }
```

If `List` were a class component, this would have worked. But since `List` is a function component, TypeScript rejects this. What is the type of `List` here so that I can use it inside `IListsProps`? I don't want to use a generic `any`, or `JSX.Element` type.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using another name for your `List` component as it is a default Type already you could use `typeof` instead, but it is irritation IMHO.

```
export function List() { 

}

export interface IListsProps {
    lists: typeof List[];
}

export default function Lists({ lists }: IListsProps) { 
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you will need to make an interface for your list object.

For example

```
export interface employee = {
 id: number,
 name: string,
 status: string
};
```

after that, you can import the object type into your component and define it for the props type.